# Wiping or encrypting memory for NSObjects

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory, nsobject

I'm trying to figure out if there is a general way to essentially wipe or encrypt the memory associated with NSObjects. I don't really care if it's a bit cumbersome, I just want to make sure it really can't be read.

For example if I have an

```
NSString* str = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"TESTING"];
```

it's relatively simple to do

```
unsigned char* strPtr = (unsigned char *) CFStringGetCStringPtr
    ((CFStringRef) str, CFStringGetSystemEncoding());
memset(strPtr, 0, [str length]);
```

And I can do similar things for NSData. But I would really like to have something more general.

I have looked into, with no luck:

- Zones, which seem like they are no longer used.
- Creating a parent class of NSObject and casting everything to that and keeping track of the memory regions. This has just been a complete pain though.
- Encrypting the actual contents of the data and forcing a decrypt on access. This gets back to the problem of knowing something about every single type.
- Encrypting then decrypting memory regions, can't find a way to reliably know where in memory a general object is.

Any hints or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why must the data be encrypted while in memory? File encryption is normal, because others can potentially access those files without much difficulty. Not so simple with objects in memory. Understanding your motivation may help find a better solution

Comment: I would like to at least be able to wipe memory after use and it would just be a bonus if I could additionally lock/unlock memory (i.e. grab some password from the keychain and decrypt portions as needed).  I'm trying to minimize the damage an attacker could do given that they get physical access to the device.  I have several other controls in place (encrypted persistence, jailbreak detection, etc.) but a sophisticated attacker can still just dump/cold boot the memory.  I've been individually picking out things and wipe as needed, but this is really problematic when inheriting code.

Comment: @GavinBlack even if they could dump the RAM it would be very difficult to identify the data unless it's all plain strings that would give it away... To clear the memory you could always memset(object, 0, sizeof(NSObject)); or something like that before release..

Comment: @GavinBlack with a password or string data, you could always encrypt it yourself and just store it in it's encrypted state until needed...

Comment: If you need something encrypted, store it that way in a file. While the data is in memory there is basically no chance of it being interpreted correctly by someone else unless they had some very intimate knowledge of your application somehow. If you want the heap memory of your sensitive data cleared with no possible trace, do as @JustinMeiners suggested with memset.

Comment: @JustinMeiners agreed it is difficult to identify values in RAM, but I'm considering the case of high value data where it maybe worth reconstructing.  Also I realize I could encrypt it myself and store it per instance, but this is something I'm doing many times over different code bases and isn't necessarily limited to just strings (That was my example since it's short). For example an NSDictionary, NSSet, etc. can all be holding sensitive information and may need this protection.  Instead of writing handlers for every type of common NSObject I wanted to generalize.

Comment: @PatrickGoley again the use case is to protect the memory, doesn't help much to store it in a file :) Everything persisted is already encrypted (sqlcipher).

Comment: @JustinMeiners Forgot to mention that sizeof does not work unfortunately :( sizeof(NSObject) is the size of the pointer not the actual space in memory.  malloc_size seems like it also does the same thing for NSObject (Always 32 on my architecture), but works with primitives.

Comment: Even if you are able to encrypt the data somehow in memory, it will exist in memory in some other instance before or after encryption when you need to actually use the data. Even if you have one encrypted instance, other instances likely exist at some point that are not.

Comment: also, try sizeOf(&NSObject). This will dereference the pointer to the actual bytes of data.

Comment: @PatrickGoley &NSObject doesn't seem to work, always returns 4 on my architecture, and not 100% sure why.  I did find I was being dumb with malloc_size though, it pads up to the word boundary so it never seemed like it was changing, but it actually does.  Now the issue I'm stuck on is where does the data actually start in memory.  The NSObject's pointer is to the 'struct' itself for an NSObject. That's why for String I have to do the whole CFStringGetCStringPtr.

Comment: This would be much easier to accomplish in C++ it would seem. Objective-C is designed against bit grubbing operations such as this. You may consider writing this portion of your code using C++ instead to avoid the protective layer of Objective-C

Comment: Or C so you don't have to open up the objective C++ can of worms.

Comment: You can't simply do a memset on the NSObject because you also have to clear all the data it's pointing to. For example, if you have a char* as an instance variable of an NSObject, memsetting the object would not erase the data in the char array, only the pointer. Also, &object returns the memory address.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a category to NSObject that uses reflection via the runtime API. This can be used to clear ivars/properties, even properties declared as readonly.

One drawback is that it does not clear certain properties, such as the frame of a UIView, and I'm not sure why it misses that.

NSObject+Scrub.h:

```
@interface NSObject (Scrub)

- (void) scrub;

@end
```

NSObject+Scrub.m:

```
#import "NSObject+Scrub.h"
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@implementation NSObject (Scrub)

- (void) scrub
{
    Class myClass = [self class];

    unsigned int count;

    //Scrub the Ivars
    Ivar *ivars = class_copyIvarList(myClass, &count);
    for (int i = 0; i < count ; i++) {
        Ivar ivar = ivars[i];
        object_setIvar(self, ivar, nil);
    }
    free(ivars);

}

@end
```

Good luck!

Comment: Interesting idea, and seems to work for many cases.  You are correct though that it does not seem to clear every type of object.  Especially anything